# Python: change NaN to a specific value taken from a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to assign a variable to a dataframe but the value is only assigned to the first row, the rest are Nan. I can only find documentation on how to turn a NaN value to zero.

I have the following data:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'One': ['a value', 'another value', 'okay', 'yes'],'Two': ['var', 'var2', 'alright', 'pool']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['One', 'Two'])
```

I also have this list of dictionaries:

```py
d = [{'year': '1997', 'name': 'John', 'another_dict': 'dict'}]
```

I want to assign the `year` from the list of dictionaries. I'm not interested in any of the other dictionaries, only the year one. To assign it to my df I did this:

converted list of dictionaries to a df

```py
dr = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='columns')

# strip the year column from the data

acad_year = dr["year"]

# join to the original data

new_data = df.join(acad_year)

print(new_data)
```

The issue is that `1997` is only assigned in the first row, after that I get NaN values. Does anyone know how I can do this so that each value in the 'year' column is '1997'? I realise this is quite protracted so if there is generally a better way to assign 'year' to the dataframe please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a scalar to a column

```py
df['year'] = 1997
```

From your dictionary

```py
df['year'] = d[0]['year']
```

From your dataframe

```py
df['year'] = dr['year'][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have to work from these two dicts I'd just use your current method to create two dataframes then use

```
df['year'] = acad_year.iloc[0]
```